# RadGridview, RowVisibility collapsed when scrolling

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, telerik

I have a **RadExpander**, inside of it I have a **RadGridView** with a **ToggleColumn**. The problem is that when a row has a large content if I try to scroll to the right to see the end of the text the current row gets collapsed. The rows are autoGenerated, in case that has something to do.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's the solution, the problem had to do with the type of toggle column I was using..

```
<UserControl x:Class="RadGridView_SL5_AR_34.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:RadGridView_SL5_AR_34"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="700">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <my:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}">
        <Grid Background="#FFB9B9B9">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <telerik:RadExpander x:Name="expanderRunningReqs"
                                 IsExpanded="False"
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                 telerik:AnimationManager.IsAnimationEnabled="True"
                                 Grid.Row="1">
                <telerik:RadExpander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Clubs"
                                   Margin="5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </telerik:RadExpander.Header>
                <telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdClubs"
                                         Margin="3"
                                         ShowGroupPanel="False"
                                         RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                                         IsReadOnly="True"
                                         MaxHeight="300"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                         CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Clubs}">
                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn />
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name"
                                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Established}"
                                                        Header="Established"
                                                        DataFormatString="{} {0:dd, MMM, yyyy H:mm}" />
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="StadiumCapacity"
                                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding StadiumCapacity}" />
                        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                        <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdDetails"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
                                 ShowGroupPanel="False"
                                 RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 IsReadOnly="True"
                                 MaxHeight="200"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                 CanUserFreezeColumns="False">
                                    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                                Header="Name" />
                                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Number}"
                                                Header="Number" />
                                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Country"
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Country}"
                                                MinWidth="150" />
                                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Position"
                                                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position}"
                                                MinWidth="500" />
                                    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                </telerik:RadGridView>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadGridView>
                </telerik:RadExpander.Content>
            </telerik:RadExpander>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```